# C++/Cli удаление раздела реестра LocalMachine

Tags: c++-cli, реестр, regedit

Столкнулся с нуждой через c++ удалять/скрывать папки Видео/Фото/и т.д из Этот компьютер.
Для этого используется редактирование реестра.
RegCreateKeyEx() и т.д из-за того что я использую cli визивают ошибку,
Win32::Registry работает но при попытке работать с LocalMachine появляется ошибка из-за того что он не может найти нужный раздел,
system(regedit файл реестра) и process->Start(regedit, файл реестра) тоже не меняют реестр.
Visual Studio запущена от имени админа, в манифесте проекта права админа тоже настроены.

Что делать дальше уже не знаю.

Comment: _визивают ошибку_ - какую ошибку? _появляется ошибка_ - какая ошибка? _не меняют реестр_ - а что происходит, какой результат?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема с RegCreateKeyEx() решилась добавлением #pragma comment(lib,"Advapi32.lib").
Теперь всьо нормально закривается.